# Updating in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

My code is supposed to display a specified image for each hour of the day. I am using pygame, and the code displays a picture fullscreen fpor each hour in a while loop for each hour of the day. When the hour switches, the picture is supposed to switch to the next picture that is supposed to display for that specified hour. I am using `pygame.display.update()` but it isn't working. Anyone know whats wrong?

Included is the first part and last part of the code. each hour has the same code, just didn't need to post all of it. Thank you

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import datetime

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), RESIZABLE)

while True:

    now = datetime.datetime.now().time()
    
    if now.hour == 1:
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), RESIZABLE | FULLSCREEN)
        pic = pygame.image.load('/Users/shaughnessyriorden/Desktop/Pictures/+11.png')
        screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(pic, (0, 0)), (0, 0))
        while now.hour == 1:
            pygame.display.flip()
            pygame.event.pump()
            event = pygame.event.wait()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.display.quit()
            elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.display.quit()
            elif event.type == VIDEORESIZE:
                screen = pygame.display.set_mode(event.dict['size'], RESIZABLE |FULLSCREEN)
                screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(pic, event.dict['size']), (0, 0))    
                pygame.display.flip()
            pygame.display.update()
    
    elif now.hour == 2:
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), RESIZABLE | FULLSCREEN)
        pic = pygame.image.load('/Users/shaughnessyriorden/Desktop/Pictures/+10.png')
        screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(pic, (0, 0)), (0, 0))
        while now.hour == 2:
            pygame.display.flip()
            pygame.event.pump()
            event = pygame.event.wait()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.display.quit()
            elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.display.quit()
            elif event.type == VIDEORESIZE:
                screen = pygame.display.set_mode(event.dict['size'], RESIZABLE |FULLSCREEN)
                screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(pic, event.dict['size']), (0, 0))    
                pygame.display.flip()
            pygame.display.update()
        
                .........

    elif now.hour == 23:
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), RESIZABLE | FULLSCREEN)
        pic = pygame.image.load('/Users/shaughnessyriorden/Desktop/Pictures/-11.png')
        screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(pic, (0, 0)), (0, 0))
        while now.hour == 23:
            pygame.display.flip()
            pygame.event.pump()
            event = pygame.event.wait()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.display.quit()
            elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.display.quit()
            elif event.type == VIDEORESIZE:
                screen = pygame.display.set_mode(event.dict['size'], RESIZABLE |FULLSCREEN)
                screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(pic, event.dict['size']), (0, 0))    
                pygame.display.flip() 
        pygame.display.update()
                
    elif now.hour == 0:
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), RESIZABLE | FULLSCREEN)
        pic = pygame.image.load('/Users/shaughnessyriorden/Desktop/Pictures/+12.png')
        screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(pic, (0, 0)), (0, 0))
        while now.hour == 0:
            pygame.display.flip()
            pygame.event.pump()
            event = pygame.event.wait()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.display.quit()
            elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.display.quit()
            elif event.type == VIDEORESIZE:
                screen = pygame.display.set_mode(event.dict['size'], RESIZABLE |FULLSCREEN)
                screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(pic, event.dict['size']), (0, 0))    
                pygame.display.flip() 
        pygame.display.update()

pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not working because the code has multiple loops, and only sets the variable `now` in the outer loop.  Then it gets "trapped" inside one of the hour-number sub-loops.  Inside these sub-loops `now` never changes.

The "quick and easy" fix is to simply update `now` inside both loops:

```
if now.hour == 1:
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), RESIZABLE | FULLSCREEN)
    pic = pygame.image.load('/Users/shaughnessyriorden/Desktop/Pictures/+11.png')
    screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(pic, (0, 0)), (0, 0))
    while now.hour == 1:
        now = datetime.datetime.now().time()     # <<-- HERE

        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.event.pump()
        event = pygame.event.wait()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.display.quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.display.quit()
        elif event.type == VIDEORESIZE:
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode(event.dict['size'], RESIZABLE |FULLSCREEN)
            screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(pic, event.dict['size']), (0, 0))    
            pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.display.update()
```

But this code is could really use some work.  It's easy to see that it's mostly the same code over and over again, with the odd slightly different parameter here and there.  The bulk of it could be reduced significantly.

By using an array of images, where the hour-offset is the index into the array, it's easy to have a single re-paint loop that just finds the correct image by its index.

```
import pygame
import os.path
from pygame.locals import *
import datetime

# Make an array of images for the 24 time-offsets
def loadAndScaleImages( screen_width, screen_height ):
    image_dir   = '/Users/shaughnessyriorden/Desktop/Pictures'
    image_names = [ '+12.png', '+11.png', '+10.png', ... '-11.png' ]
    hour_images = []
    for name in image_names:
        # load the image
        image = pygame.image.load( os.path.join( image_dir, name ) ) 
        # scale to screen-size
        image = pygame.transform.smoothscale( image, ( screen_width, screen_height ) )
        hour_images.append( image )
    return hour_images


### MAIN 
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), RESIZABLE)
screen_width, screen_height = pygame.display.get_surface().get_size()
hour_images = []    # holds the loaded and re-scaled images

# load the images in the first time
hour_images = loadAndScaleImages( screen_width, screen_height )  

# Main Loop
running = True
while running:
   
    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == VIDEORESIZE:
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode(event.dict['size'], RESIZABLE )
            screen_width, screen_height = pygame.display.get_surface().get_size()
            # We need to re-scale the images because the window-size changed
            hour_images = loadAndScaleImages( screen_width, screen_height )

    # Determine which hour-image to show
    now   = datetime.datetime.now().time()
    image = hour_images[ now.hour ]

    # Put the image to the screen
    screen.blit( image, ( 0, 0 ) )
    pygame.display.flip() 

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I tried implementing the new code you wrote, it won't load the image, it will kust show the pygame window, also what is "road_image" under the # scale to screen_size pseudo?

Comment: @ChadRiorden - `road_image` is just a paste-o, it should be `image`.  (fixed in answer)

Comment: @ChadRiorden - Hmm, yeah the image loading had a global/local scope issue.  I fixed that, and tweaked a couple of other things.  It still doesn't look correct on my dual-monitor display until the window is resized because of the way the window is opened (size 0,0) Vs X-Windows, but it's mostly there.

Comment: This code works great! thank you so much. I just started with python last month, that is why my code was rough haha. Last thing on the checklist is to display the image fullscreen, but I can just mess around with it and hopefully figure it out.

Comment: @ChadRiorden - the fullscreen can be handled with a parameter to `pygame.display.set_mode()`.

Comment: I tried  pygame.FULLSCREEN but it just flashes the fullscreen, then displays the picture normally.

Comment: @ChadRiorden - I wonder if you're getting a resize event as part of the window opening.  You'll probably need to handle it in the resize too.

Comment: I added a pygame.display.set mode outside the whole loop and it worked out... thank you so much for the help, you made my project achievable